# Ajax Autocomplete TextBox from PostgreSQL Not getting Data

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql, autocomplete

I am trying to us Ajax to call a php script which gets data from my PostgreSQL In php, my code is:

```
    <?php


# Includes
require("database.inc.php");
require("json.inc.php");

# Retrive URL arguments
$table = $_REQUEST['table'];
$fields = isset($_REQUEST['fields']) ? $_REQUEST['fields'] : '*';
$parameters = isset($_REQUEST['parameters']) ? " where " . $_REQUEST['parameters'] : '';
$order = isset($_REQUEST['order']) ? " order by " . $_REQUEST['order'] : '';
$limit = isset($_REQUEST['limit']) ? " limit " . $_REQUEST['limit'] : '';

# Perform the query
$sql = "select " . $fields . " from " . $table . $parameters . $order . $limit;
$db = pgConnection();
$statement=$db->prepare( $sql );
$statement->execute();

# send JSON or JSONP results
sendJSON($statement);

?>
```

and here is my Ajax:

```
            $.ajax({
            url: "ws_geo_attributequery.php",
            //table:'address',
            //fields:'file_as_na',
            type:'GET',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                'table:':'address',
                'fields':'file_as_na',
                id: 1

                },


            success: function(response){
                var data = $(response).map(function(){
                    return {value: this.file_as_na, id: this.id};
                }).get();

                $('#name').autocomplete({
                    source: data,
                    minLength: 0,
                    select: function(event,ui){
                        $('input#id').val(ui.item.id);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I am not getting any result from my Db.  I am sure the Problem in my ajax request.
I do appreciate any help.

Comment: Set `log_statements = all` in PostgreSQL and see what query actually arrives there.

Comment: where exactly to set that, I am using pgadmin 4

Comment: With `ALTER SYSTEM` and then `pg_reload_conf()`, if you want to do it from SQL.

Comment: the query is not working,  I am using also Mac

Comment: here is my call back from chrome developer . http://localhost/geo_v6/ws_geo_attributequery.php?callback=jQuery311044707230673828846_1527219287188&table%3A=address&fields=file_as_na&id=1&_=1527219287189

Comment: *Never* say "is not working" without describing *what* is not working *how*, particularly if you want to become a programmer.